# PHP variable scope - is the variable used anywhere?

Tags: php, scope

I am trying to read some php code, but can't understand how the variable $predicate here can be used:

```
private function getRelatedItems() {
    $predicate = Zotero_Relations::$relatedItemPredicate;

    $relations = $this->getRelations();
    if (empty($relations->$predicate)) {
        return [];
    }

    $relatedItemURIs = is_string($relations->$predicate)
        ? [$relations->$predicate]
        : $relations->$predicate;

    // Pull out object values from related-item relations, turn into items, and pull out keys
    $keys = [];
    foreach ($relatedItemURIs as $relatedItemURI) {
        $item = Zotero_URI::getURIItem($relatedItemURI);
        if ($item) {
            $keys[] = $item->key;
        }
    }
    return $keys;
}
```

As far as I can see $predicate is assigned a value that is never used. But I guess I am misunderstanding the scope somehow, or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable is used to access a property in `$relations` variable.

Here is a simplified usage example of variable property access which should clarify the usage for you:

```
$property = 'firstName';
$data = (object) array(
    'firstName' => 'Justin',
    'lastName' => 'Case',
);

echo $data->$property; //Rquivalent to $data->firstName, which eEchoes 'Justin'
```

Additionally, it works for functions, and class methods, too:

```
class Foo
{
     public function bar()
     {
         echo 'Hello, world!';
     }
}

$foo = new Foo();
$method = 'bar';

$foo->$method(); //Equivalent to $foo->bar(); Displays 'Hello, world!'


$function = 'strlen';

echo $function('Hello, world!'); //Is equivalent to calling strlen('Hello, world!');
```

It's pretty neat!

Comment: Ah, now I see it. Thanks. It looked to me like the name of the property was "$predicate" in "->$predicate". Quite confusing. ;-)

Comment: I was definitely dumfounded when I first encountered this syntax, too!  PHP is the only language I know in which all variables are preceded by a special char ($), so I really thought it was something! Here is the relevant page from the official docs: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: ;-) - Thanks, I think I am over it now.

Answer (score 3):

The `$predicate` variable holds the name of an attribute on the `$relations` object. E.g:

```
$relations->$predicate
```

If `$predicate` is set to `foo` then PHP sees the line as:

```
$relations->foo
```